# Tkinter radiobuttons are already selected when running

Tags: python, tkinter

> Hello, i am trying to create a program using radiobuttons, i am only at the beginning of it and i already have a problem. When i run my program both radiobuttons (binari_1 and binari_2) are already selected and i can't interact at all with them. I've already tried using the deselect function but for < binari_1.deselect() > it returns the error: < 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'deselect' >. What else can i do? Any help is well accepted, Thank you!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()

window.title("Controlla quote")
window.geometry('720x300')


#binari
binari=0
def binari(number):
    if number==1:
        binari=1
    elif number==2:
        binari=2
    else:
        pass
    return binari;

#radiobuttons
binari_1=Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=binari(1)).grid(column=1, row=0)
binari_2=Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=binari(2)).grid(column=2, row=0)

#binari label
binari_scritta=Label(window, text="Binari:").grid(column=0, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, don't write your question as a quote, fix this. Then, edit your question and use `\`` brackets for code expressions in the text to clarify the question.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your facing is because you dont have a value or a variable set to the radiobutton, set those and you should be good to go. Furter more, you need to use `lambda` or the function will get executed immediately.

```
var = IntVar()

binari_1 = Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=lambda:binari(var.get()),variable=var,value=1).grid(column=1, row=0)
binari_2 = Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=lambda:binari(var.get()),variable=var,value=2).grid(column=2, row=0)
```

Without `lambda`, your calling the function directly, hence before selecting any of the radiobuttons the function will be run(invoked). So use `lambda` if you want to pass in any arguments to function.

> **Syntax:** `lambda <parameters> : <expression or another function>`

Further more you get a `NoneType` error because, you `grid()` on the same line of declaration, so just say:

```
binari_1 = Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=lambda:binari(var.get()),variable=var,value=1)
binari_1.grid(column=1, row=0)

binari_2 = Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=lambda:binari(var.get()),variable=var,value=2)
binari_2.grid(column=2, row=0)
```

Comment: I tried that but i still get the same problem unfortunately.  I'll leave a screenshot of the program after running it at this link ----> https://imgur.com/Xfx2Mbg . Oh and i still can't interact woth the radiobuttons

Comment: I tried using your new code, with and without the deselect() function. It still not works. It runs with no problems and no errors but the buttons are "selected" and non interactable in both cases.

Comment: @FrancescoRuffinengo Perhaps your missing something, ill update with the entire code. and lemme know

Comment: Thank you very much for the immidiate help!!! It worked, and yes i was missing some code 

Comment: @FrancescoRuffinengo Also i might recommend changing `binari=0` to `binari_num=0` having function and variable in same name is not recommended, this will result in recursion or further errors in your case